# I'm trying to edit an item by passing its ID, however when the item is returned it comes back as a new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to edit an item by having it sent to another form

```
Private Sub btnEditItem_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_btnEditItem_Click
    status = 1
    Flag = 0
    Dim i, PID, ID As Integer
    PID = Me.intID_PK
      i = Me.intEstimateID_fk
     ID = Me.intItemID_fk

    If Nz(intItemID_fk, 0) <> 0 Then
      DoCmd.openform "frmEditItem", , , "[intID_PK]=" & ID, acFormEdit, , i & ";" & ID & ";" & PID
        Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Exit_btnEditItem_Click:
        Exit Sub

    Err_btnEditItem_Click:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_btnEditItem_Click

End Sub
```

"frmEditItem" this is the form I'm using to try and edit the item. Once the necessary modifications have been made, I would like this item to save as the item I was editing, yet it saves as a new item at the bottom of the list. When I do an AcFormEdit or without having any Openform mode it sends the item to the top of the list and removes whichever item was at the top.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_btnSave_Click

        If fieldcheck = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70

         If Nz(Credit, "") = 0 Then
            If CreditLimit2 = False Then
               'Exit Sub
            End If
         End If
        status = 1
        Flag = 0
        'Refresh the form
        Forms!frmAddEstimate!frmSubEstimateItem.Requery
        ID = Me.intEstimateID_fk
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.openform "frmAddEstimate", , , "[intEstimateID_pk]=" & ID, acFormAdd
```

Answer (score 1):

This line  `DoCmd.openform "frmAddEstimate", , , "[intEstimateID_pk]=" & ID, acFormAdd` specifically to **acFormAdd** will open your form set to create a new record. Remove the argument `acFormAdd`

Comment: check if your form `frmAddEstimate` is set to `DataEntry` = Yes.